# php files aren't loaded, due to unknown apache errors

Tags: php, macos, apache, console, firefox-developer-edition

I am using apache to run `php` files in `firefox dev` edition but some of them won't work.

I guess its because of the following errors that are being shown in console for

> apache2: [Mon Dec 18 08:57:59.610192 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 121] AH00163: Apache/2.4.28 (Unix) PHP/7.1.7 configured --
>   resuming normal operations
>
> [Mon Dec 18 08:57:59.610276 2017] [core:notice] [pid 121] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND' .

If I click "submit" in my self-made register form, it is supposed to open the next file, which fails:

Comment: Could you add the code from a page that doesn't work.

Comment: The things, which you have posted are not errors. They are just normal logs, that Apache is running..

Comment: @NigelRen I am trying to but they dont allow me to post urls to files

Comment: You need to add the code to your question, paste the code lines in. (try and get the smallest piece of code which fails)

Comment: @Geshode I found them in the file error_log file inside apache2

Comment: @NigelRen I did, even though stackoverflow thinks its html

Comment: I see. But these two are just notices and not errors.

Comment: What does your signup.php look like. Have you tried to put the complete path into the header?

Comment: @Gesthode I have. I need 10 reputation for it hahaha. Here they are: <https://imgur.com/a/1cgX0>. (I know, the link does not work. Stackoverflow makes me crazy. Please send me an email at tomadelmeijer@xs4all.nl and I'll send you all of the relevant files and images.) The file and what it looks like when I click "signup". the url was supposed to show "submit=success" or "access=success" or some whit at the end.